# SQL query to get users who are following someone and being followed back by same person

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a scenario in which I want to find users who are following user **X** and user **X** is following them back.

Look at the following schema:
[database_table_with_test_values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWQdc.png)

we have follower_id and following_id,
now lets say we want to check if user with id 23 is following someone and they are following him back.

as you can see user 22 is following user 23 back,
so we want to get user 22 details from users table such as name and email.

user 23 is following 24 but user 24 is not following user 23 back so we wont include user 24 in our list.

Please help me write the query to get the list of users for above scenario.
Thanks

**Update**

As I needed more info on User. A slow solution I am implementing for now in laravel.

```
        $UsersIAmFollowing = UserFollowing::where('follower_id', $user->id)->get();
        $UsersFollowingMe = UserFollowing::where('following_id', $user->id)->get();
        $friends = [];
        foreach ($UsersIAmFollowing as $userIamFollowing) {
            foreach ($UsersFollowingMe as $userFollowingMe) {
                if($userIamFollowing->following_id == $userFollowingMe->follower_id){
                    array_push($friends, User::find($userIamFollowing->following_id));
                }
            }
        }

        dd($friends);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.id 
      ,t.follower_id    
      ,t.following_id
from   t join t t2 on t2.following_id = t.follower_id 
         and          t.following_id = t2.follower_id
```

| id | follower_id | following_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 22 | 23 |
| 6 | 23 | 22 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FVdEle8u?hide=4)

Comment: Hi thanks for taking your time to write this query, it was really helpful and I was getting users but I needed more info about users from users table. And I only wanted to get user id of user being followed by X. not the record of X itself following other user.

Comment: You can just add that info to the select